# Reading YAML files and accessing lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, key, yaml

I am currently reading data from a .yml file. Inside the file is the following part for every main entry:

```
- !
  name: Martial Focus
  prerequisites:
    tier1:
      any:
        Attribute:
        - Attribute1:§ 1
        - Attribute2:§ 1
        Feat:
        - Feat1
        Other:
        - Other Prerequisites
  cost:
  - 3
  description: |
    [...]
  effect: |
    [...]
```

I've been able to read all the data, including 'prerequisites', but here I have a special problem:
Where with the other data, I was able to access sublists it seems to be different for this:

The "any:" part is optional, so it could also say something like

```
prerequisites:
    tier1:
      Attribute:
      - Attribute1:§ 1
      - Attribute2:§ 1
      Feat:
      - Feat1
      Other:
      - Other Prerequisites
```

Reading the .yml file converts the part above to

```
'prerequisites': {
  'tier1': {
    'any': {
      'Attribute': ['Attribute1:§ 1', 'Attribute2:§ 1'],
      'Feat': ['Feat1'],
      'Other': ['Other Prerequisites']
    }
  }
}
```

So in my code, for every "tierX", I check if it contains a key "any:" via

```
if 'any' in tier:
  # do the stuff to be done if 'any' exists
else:
  # do the stuff to be done if it doesn't
```

But it never seems to be true. Since "Attribute:", "Feat:" and "Other:" are also optional, I do the same for those inside the if-else-statement and it's the same problem with them though for those there's no else-statement.
Below you can find the code I'm using. It won't be the prettiest since I litterally started with python today but I hope that you'll help me anyway:

```
        prerequisites = ""
        tierNum = 0
        for tier in data['prerequisites']:
            tierNum += 1
            thisTier = ""
            if 'any' in tier:
                print("'any' found!")
                content = tier['any']
                if 'Other' in content:
                    other = ""
                    for s2 in content['Other'][:-1]:
                        other += s2 + ", "
                    thisTier += "**" + other
                    if len(content['Other'][:-1]) == 0:
                        thisTier += str(content['Other'][-1:])
                    else:
                        thisTier += "or " + str(content['Other'][-1:])

                    if 'Attribute' in content:
                        attributes = ""
                        for s2 in content['Attribute'][:-1]:
                            attributes += s2 + ", "
                        if thisTier.length() == 0:
                            thisTier += "**" + attributes
                        else:
                            thisTier += ", or " + attributes
                        if len(content['Attribute'][:-1]) == 0:
                            thisTier += str(content['Attribute'][-1:])
                        else:
                            thisTier += "or " + str(content['Attribute'][-1:])

                    if 'Feat' in content:
                        feats = ""
                        for s2 in content['Feat'][:-1]:
                            feats += s2 + ", "
                        if thisTier.length() == 0:
                            thisTier += "**" + feats
                        else:
                            thisTier += ", or " + feats
                        if len(content['Feat'][:-1]) == 0:
                            thisTier += str(content['Feat'][-1:])
                        else:
                            thisTier += "or " + str(content['Feat'][-1:])

            else:
                content = tier
                if 'Other' in content:
                    other = ""
                    for s2 in content['Other'][:-1]:
                        other +=  s2 + ", "
                    thisTier += "**" + other
                    if len(content['Other'][:-1]) == 0:
                        thisTier += str(content['Other'][-1:])
                    else:
                        thisTier += "or " + str(content['Other'][-1:])

                if 'Attribute' in content:
                    attributes = ""
                    for s2 in content['Attribute'][:-1]:
                        attributes += s2 + ", "
                    thisTier += "**" + attributes
                    if len(content['Attribute'][:-1]) == 0:
                        thisTier += str(content['Attribute'][-1:])
                    else:
                        thisTier += "or " + str(content['Attribute'][-1:])

                if 'Feat' in content:
                    feats = ""
                    for s2 in content['Feat'][:-1]:
                        feats += s2 + ", "
                    thisTier += "**" + feats
                    if len(content['Feat'][:-1]) == 0:
                        thisTier += str(content['Feat'][-1:])
                    else:
                        thisTier += "or " + str(content['Feat'][-1:])

            prerequisites += "*Tier {0}:\n{1}\n".format(tierNum, thisTier)
        prerequisites = prerequisites[:-1]
```

I'm doing stuff like the `content['Feat'][:-1]` in order to get every element except the last so I can add a `", or "` in front of the last element, should there be more than one.

**EDIT:**
My desired Output would be something like:

```
Prerequisites:
*Tier 1:
**Attribute1 1, or Attribute2 1
**Feat1
**Other Prerequisites
```

If no any exists and

```
Prerequisites:
*Tier 1:
**Attribute1 1, or Attribute2 1, or Feat1, or Other Prerequisites
```

if it doesn't

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: Edited my post to include that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `for tier in data["predicates"]` iterates over the **keys** of the predicate dictionary, thus the subsequent `if "any" in tier` actually evaluates `"any" in "tier1"` which is of cause always false.

---

What you want to test here is `"any" in data["predicates"]["tier1"]`. When working with dictionaries (i.e. mappings) you have to differentiate between a `key` and its corresponding `value`.

Interestingly you have gotten it right for the next level down:

```
# ...
content = tier['any']
if 'Other' in content:
    other = ""
    for s2 in content['Other']:
       # ...
```

---

Ways to iterate over a dictionary

```
d = {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"}
for key in d:
  print(key)
# prints key1, key2, key3
for key in d.keys():
  print(key)
# prints key1, key2, key3
for value in d.values():
  print(value)
# prints value1, value2, value3
for item in d.items():
  print(item)
# prints (key1,value1), (key2,value2), (key3,value3)
for key, value in d.items():
  print(key)
  print(value)
# prints key1, value1, key2, value2, key3, value3
```

---

see python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

---

As you are new to Python and do not know what is possible, allow me to present you a much more elegant solution with out all the repetitive string operations:

```
import yaml


yamldata1 = r"""
- !
  name: Martial Focus
  prerequisites:
    tier1:
      any:
        Attribute:
        - Attribute1:§ 1
        - Attribute2:§ 1
        Feat:
        - Feat1
        Other:
        - Other Prerequisites
  cost:
  - 3
  description: |
    [...]
  effect: |
    [...]
"""
yamldata2 = r"""
- !
  name: Martial Focus
  prerequisites:
    tier1:
        Attribute:
        - Attribute1:§ 1
        - Attribute2:§ 1
        Feat:
        - Feat1
        Other:
        - Other Prerequisites
  cost:
  - 3
  description: |
    [...]
  effect: |
    [...]
"""


def process(data):
    output = ""
    for tier_name, tier in data['prerequisites'].items():
        output += f"* {tier_name}"
        if 'any' in tier:
            content = tier['any']
            prerequisites = content.get('Other', []) + content.get('Attribute', []) + content.get('Feat', [])
            if prerequisites:
                output += "\n** " + " or ".join(prerequisites)
        else:
            content = tier
            prerequisites = [content.get('Other', []), content.get('Attribute', []), content.get('Feat', [])]

            for subset in prerequisites:
                if subset:
                    output += "\n** " + " or ".join(subset)
    return output


data = yaml.load(yamldata1)[0]
print(process(data))
print('#'*10)
data = yaml.load(yamldata2)[0]
print(process(data))
```

Comment: But that's what I want it to do, isn't it? For every tier, I want to check if there is an 'any' key in there.

Comment: I am confused. Is that not what the `for tier in data['prerequisites']` is for?
What would be the correct expression?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get where my problem is ._.

Comment: Am I not looking for a key called 'any' in every tier with my `if 'any' in tier`?

Comment: `data['prerequisites']` is a dictionary not a list! If you iterate over a dictionary you actually iterate over its keys so your `tier` variable will contain the string `"tier1"` not the corresponding part of your data structure which would be `data['prerequisites']['tier1']`.

Comment: Thank you! One question though: what does the f in `output += f"* {tier_name}"` do?

Comment: Is there a way to join the subsets of e.g. Attributes with a ", " instead of all "or"s?

Comment: ``f"* {tier_name}"` so called string interpolation, the newest of the string formatting methods. Equivalent to `"* {0}".format(tier_name)` or the even older `"* %s" % tier_name`

Comment: The string on which you call `join` defines the separator. So `", "`.join(['a','b','c'])` returns `"a, b, c"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168948/discussion-between-petere-and-lithimlin).